# How to just limit the displaying of new message box in Django channels

Tags: django, notifications, django-channels

I am trying to make a real-time message notification.The scenario I am having is user sends a message to user2 he gets a notification that you have a message from user2.In that inbox there are the recent 3 messages.

I wanna make it like that the inbox messages should be limited to those 3 boxes.If he gets a new message.No box should be created instead the recent message box should be rewritten with that information.If he gets 3 new messages from 3 different users.Those 3 recent message box should be updated with those messages instead of creating new boxes.Think about it like a Facebook messaging hovered inbox.I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

A) Persist the messages in the DB as normal records (since users might not be online when the message is sent)

B) When a message is updated/inserted send a message to the channel layer group for that user. (use the recipients `id` as the group name include the message-id in this event).

C) in your WebSocket consumer, you will subscribe to the group for the connected user.

D) When the event handler is triggered in your consumer I would read the message from the DB and send it to the client.